# contact identifier ついて

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

contact identifierに紐付けされたcoredataを利用して連絡先を拡張したアプリを作りたいのですが、itunes等でバックアップ後他の端末に復元後のidentifierは維持されますか？

維持されない場合の紐付けの方法などヒント等でも構いませんのでご教授願いたいです。
よろしくお

Answer (score 1):

質問されているのが、Contacts FrameworkのCNContactのidentifierの事だと仮定して回答します。

Appleの資料からは他の端末で復元した場合の情報を見つけられなかったので、手もとの環境で実際に試してみました。

- iTunesでバックアップして同じ端末に復元した場合
  identifierは変化せず
- iTunesでバックアップして違う端末に復元した場合
  identifierは変化せず
- iCloud経由で違う端末と同期した場合
  identifierは別の値になった

とりあえず、iTunesでバックアップ＆復元をする限りはidentifierが変化することはなさそうです。ただ、変化しないことがAppleから保証されているわけでもないので、いざというときのことは考えておいたほうが良いかと思いますが。

Comment: 回答が随分遅くなりました。わざわざ試していただきありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。